# TextInputLayout has no effect for giving hint programmatically in EditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have an EditText and it's parent is TextInputLayout.
I am trying to give hint programmatically for EditText, (not in layout)
in this case Text input hint animation is not working, it's working like simple EditText. can some one suggest how to handle it.

below is my layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/post_EditTextPostAnAd"
        style="@style/abc_EditView" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You have to set hint to **TextInputLayout**
Here is the code.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);
textInputLayout.setHint("Hello");
```

**Updated**

In Kotlin:

```
val textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout)
textInputLayout.hint = "Hello"
```

Comment: Glad to know that it working....this is strange but you have to set hint to TextInputLayout programmatically to show in on floating label .

Comment: The code breaks Accessibility support (TalkBack). 
The only working solution I've come up with 
`
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);

textInputLayout.setHint("Hello");
textInputLayout.getEditText().setHint(hint);                 textInputLayout.getEditText().setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));`